# Singleton Synchronization C++

Tags: c++, design-patterns, singleton, ipc

If I have to write a singleton class in C++ I will be using a static variable, private constructor & a public static function that returns an object of class. However in Multithreaded environments the code will have problems. In order to avoid multiple threads access the same variable at the same time, is Boost threads best mechanism to use for synchronization? I mean for setting/unsetting a lock/mutex across the resource. Is there anything else inbuilt in C++ standard library where in I dont have to download boost, build stuff etc? I have heard of C++ Ox but dont know much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C++98/03 have nothing to support threads at all. If you're using a C++98 or 03 compiler, you're pretty much stuck with using Boost, or something (more or less) OS-specific, such as pthreads or Win32's threading primitives.

C++11 has a reasonably complete thread support library, with mutexes, locks, thread-local storage, etc.

I feel obliged to point out, however, that it may be better to back up and do a bit more thinking about whether you need/want a Singleton at all. To put it nicely, the singleton pattern has fallen out of favor to a large degree.

Edit: Rereading this, I kind of skipped over one thing I'd intended to say: at least when I've used them, any/all singletons were fully initialized before any secondary thread was started. That renders concern over thread safety in their initialization completely moot. I suppose there could be a singleton that you can't initialize before you start up secondary threads so you'd need to deal with this, but at least right off it strikes me as a rather unusual exception that I'd deal with only when/if absolutely necessary.

Comment: I haven't seen anything to suggest that the singleton pattern has fallen out of favor among actual practitioners.  (Of course, it was never used extensively among them either.  Only when appropriate, which isn't that often.)

Comment: I have seen many `Singleton`s but none of them necessary. Just make one and pass it around.

Comment: To put it crudely: a `Singleton` is generally a design error. Though... I agree that it is convenient for logging schemes (much more so than passing a `Logger` object in every single function).

Comment: @JamesKanze: Perhaps more accurate wording would be that a much larger number of practitioners have realized how rarely they're appropriate.

Comment: I think most of us realized it from the start.  There convenient for a couple of specific uses, and it's rare to find an application that doesn't use one or two.  But it's equally rare to find one that uses many more.  In my applications, I generally have three: one for logging, one for the configuration data, and one which is used in parsing command line arguments.  There might occasionally be a fourth, but that's about it.  And that situation hasn't changed since I started C++.  (And there seems to be a consensus about this use---at least over the places I've worked.)

Comment: @PeterWood You can't "make one and pass it around" when it's needed before you enter main.  (Not to mention that making one and passing it around tends to break encapsulation.)

Comment: @JamesKanze Lets assume that nothing important exists before `main`. It will make modular software easier to develop. I'm not sure about breaking encapsulation. In what way don't singletons have the same effect?

Comment: @PeterWood Let's assume that pi is exactly `3.0`.  It will make software easier to develop.  In C++, things do exist before `main`, and you have to take them into account.  (More importantly, things exist unknown to `main`; this is one or C++'s main features.)  And having to pass an argument down through many layers which don't need to know about it breaks encapsulation.

Comment: @JamesKanze I feel we've wandered into an argument together, and it's not really appropriate here. Maybe we can continue elsewhere. I think we share values of wanting clear, reasonable code.

Answer (score 1):

For me the best way to implement a singleton using c++11 is:

```
class Singleton
{
public:
static Singleton & Instance()
{
    // Since it's a static variable, if the class has already been created,
    // It won't be created again.
    // And it **is** thread-safe in C++11.

    static Singleton myInstance;

    // Return a reference to our instance.
    return myInstance;
}

// delete copy and move constructors and assign operators
Singleton(Singleton const&) = delete;             // Copy construct
Singleton(Singleton&&) = delete;                  // Move construct
Singleton& operator=(Singleton const&) = delete;  // Copy assign
Singleton& operator=(Singleton &&) = delete;      // Move assign

// Any other public methods

protected:
Singleton() 
{
   // Constructor code goes here.
}

~Singleton()
{
    // Destructor code goes here.
}

 // And any other protected methods.
}
```

This is a c++11 feature but with this way you can create a thread safe Singleton. According to new standard there is no need to care about this problem any more. Object initialization will be made only by one thread, other threads will wait till it complete. Or you can use std::call_once.

If you want to make a exclusive access to the singleton's resources you have to use a lock at these functions.

The different type of locks:

Using **atomic_flg_lck:**

```
class SLock
{
public:
  void lock()
  {
    while (lck.test_and_set(std::memory_order_acquire));
  }

  void unlock()
  {
    lck.clear(std::memory_order_release);
  }

  SLock(){
    //lck = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT;
    lck.clear();
  }
private:
  std::atomic_flag lck;// = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT;
};
```

Using **atomic:**

```
class SLock
{
public:
  void lock()
  {
    while (lck.exchange(true));
  }

  void unlock()
  {
    lck = true;
  }

  SLock(){
    //lck = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT;
    lck = false;
  }
private:
  std::atomic<bool> lck;
};
```

Using **mutex:**

```
class SLock
{
public:
  void lock()
  {
    lck.lock();
  }

  void unlock()
  {
    lck.unlock();
  }

private:
  std::mutex lck;
};
```

Just for **Windows**:

```
class SLock
{
public:
  void lock()
  {
    EnterCriticalSection(&g_crit_sec);
  }

  void unlock()
  {
    LeaveCriticalSection(&g_crit_sec);
  }

  SLock(){
    InitializeCriticalSectionAndSpinCount(&g_crit_sec, 0x80000400);
  }

private:
  CRITICAL_SECTION g_crit_sec;
};
```

The **atomic** and **and atomic_flg_lck** keep the thread in a spin count. **Mutex** just sleeps the thread. If the wait time is too long maybe is better sleep the thread. The last one "**CRITICAL_SECTION**" keeps the thread in a spin count until a time is consumed, then the thread goes to sleep.

How to use these critical sections?

```
unique_ptr<SLock> raiilock(new SLock());

class Smartlock{
public:
  Smartlock(){ raiilock->lock(); }
  ~Smartlock(){ raiilock->unlock(); }
};
```

Using the raii idiom. The constructor to lock the critical section and the destructor to unlock it.

Example

```
class Singleton {

   void syncronithedFunction(){
      Smartlock lock;
      //.....
   }

}
```

This implementation is thread safe and exception safe because the variable lock is saved  in the stack so when the function scope is ended (end of function or an exception) the destructor will be called.

I hope that you find this helpful.

Thanks!!